# Using Bootstrap to achieve a template like Facebook home page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I trying to use Bootstrap to create a four column layout like Facebook. Two of the columns on the right would not scroll like sidebars the other two in the center can scroll. I have tried but not getting good result.

Comment: have you tried using http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix for your two side columns?

Comment: yeah that is what I am using

Comment: Do you have an example or can you create a jsFiddle of this?

Comment: I got a template that as some stuffs of that kind

Comment: so I use media queries to manipulate it for smaller screen devices